# How can I remove the logo image in the dashboard package?

Tags: use-package, dashboard

I'd like to remove the image of the Emacs cow from the startup screen, but I want to keep my recent files, bookmarks, and agenda. Currently, I'm using the `dashboard` package with `use-package`.

My current configuration:

```
(use-package dashboard
  :ensure t
  :config
  (dashboard-setup-startup-hook)
  (setq initial-buffer-choice (lambda () (get-buffer "*dashboard*"))))
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not a cow, it's a [gnu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnu).

Comment: @db48x: It may be a gnu cow or bull.

Answer (score 3):

Try `(setq dashboard-startup-banner nil)` with this variable you can set the image or text at startup. See the docs of that variable for details.

As far as I understand the package comes with its own set of startup/images but this also can be adjusted to use own stuff.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I don't have the reputation to do so, but this should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the dashboard package, but you can control what image is used on the default splash screen by setting `fancy-splash-image`. It's probably a safe assumption that dashboard will respect the same setting.

Answer (score 0):

In your `:config` commands add `(setq dashboard-startup-banner 'nil)`.